# Как пробросить ssh-ключ в докер?

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, ssh-key, dockerfile

Во время сборки контейнера мне нужно использовать ssh-ключ машины, на которой это происходит. Как правильно пробросить ключи внутрь контейнера?

Comment: как и [любой другой файл/каталог](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: Миллион советов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container/24937401